# How to create an api with specific data from two tables from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm learning by some tutorial on the web to create an api rest with Entity Framework. I've already created a simple api from SQL Server database (with "simple" i mean that is an api from one table). Right now i wanna create an api with very specific info from two tables.

Let's say i have this two tables:

Table 1: dbo.Brands

1. IdBrand
2. BrandName
3. CreationDate

Table 2: dbo.Candies

1. IdCandy
2. IdBrand
3. Flavor
4. Size
5. NetWeight
6. IdStore

And from this two tables, i want to creat an api thar returns:

- BrandName
- Flavor
- Size

As you can see, both tables are relationed with IdBrand. For all the different things i've found on the web and tutorials, i followed the next steps:

- Create New Proyect: Aplication web ASP.NET (.Net Framework)
- Select Web API
- Add Class ADO.NET Entity Data Model
- Select EF Designer from existing DataBase
- Create new conection to SQL Server DB
- Select version of Entity Framework
- Select the tables (dbo.Brands and dboCandies)
- Create a controller per table

My doubts starts after all this steps. Where i select this three fields that i need to return? And also need to search per BrandName. Where i configure this search?

Sorry for the doubts, but all the different info around the web get me confused.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You could always create a SQL Stored Procedure and call that in the API

Comment: You don't want a controller per table. You want a Controller per business object. Your object seems to be a combination of BrandName, Flavor, and Size. You can create an object that represents that and Map your tables to that new object.

However I would try and make your problem a lot smaller for stack overflow. Try some stuff, post what you have tried ,and ask a specific question on what is wrong.